# printing invalid input from string in Java

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am trying to print the invalid number, number which is not of type `int` or `double` but not getting desired output, please help me pointing out my mistake and another thing is it is possible to to find out invalid number using some other way?

```
public class Test {
            public static void main(String [] args)
        {

        String [] str ={ "10.20","30450","12.valid","100.200"};

            for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
            {
                if(str[i].indexOf(".")>0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
                        System.out.println("its a valid int nummber : "+str[i]);
                    }
                    catch(NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("its invalid number in string: "+str[i]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Double.parseDouble(str[i]);
                        System.out.println("its valid double number: "+str[i]);
                    }

                    catch(NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("its invalid char in string : "+str[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

output

> its invalid number is string: 10.20
>
> its valid double number: 30450
>
> its invalid number is string: 12.valid
>
> its invalid number is string: 100.200

Comment: This condition is wrong: `if(str[i].indexOf(".")>0)`. It should be `if(str[i].indexOf(".") == -1)` so that you try to parse it as an `int` if there *isn't* a `.`. Did you try debugging before asking? It's important to develop you diagnostic skills.

Comment: Thank you sir, it did helped me , sir i was trying to figure out my mistake but i think i missed it >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code inside if/else should be the other way around:

```
               if(str[i].indexOf(".")>0)
                {
                   ///parse for double
                }
                else
                {
                   //parse for int
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (str[i].indexOf(".") > 0) {
```

with this

```
if (str[i].indexOf(".") < 0) {
```

**output**

```
its valid double number: 10.20
its a valid int nummber : 30450
its invalid char in string : 12.valid
its valid double number: 100.200
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
            public static void main(String [] args)
        {

        String [] str ={ "10.20","30450","12.valid","100.200"};

            for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
            {
                if(str[i].indexOf(".") == -1)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
                        System.out.println("its a valid int nummber : "+str[i]);
                    }
                    catch(NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("its invalid number in string: "+str[i]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Double.parseDouble(str[i]);
                        System.out.println("its valid double number: "+str[i]);
                    }

                    catch(NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("its invalid char in string : "+str[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Output is:

```
its valid double number: 10.20
its a valid int nummber : 30450
its invalid char in string : 12.valid
its valid double number: 100.200
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the regular expression.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z]");
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[\.]");

String [] str ={ "10.20","30450","12.valid","100.200"};
 for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
      {

        if (p.matcher(str[i]).find())
         {

               System.out.println("its invalid number in string: "+str[i]);

         }
         else (p1.matcher(str[i]).find()){

           System.out.println("its invalid char in string : "+str[i]);

        }
        else{

          System.out.println("its a valid int nummber : "+str[i]);
       }
}
```